# check library version hdf5 linux

Tags: linux, static-libraries, hdf5

how do I determine which version of the hdf5 library is installed on my system? Is there a command line? I tried to use the  `dpkg-query --list` command but it doesn't work.

I am on ubuntu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
dpkg -l | grep hdf5
```

This may help you https://superuser.com/a/690391.

Comment: that works, thanks! dpkg-query was not giving me the libhdf5 file.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the HDF5 commands will give you the version, i.e.

```
--> h5dump --version
h5dump: Version 1.10.6
```

If there is an inconsistency in the install, though, not all the components may match.